# CD-RW IDE to USB SATA PCIe interface

Tags: audio-recording

I am interested to internally integrate a CD-RW IDE unit (Plextor Plexwriter Premium 2) using the existing mainboard interface USB 3, Sata 3, PCIe mostly in burning CD's with AMQR not in ripping. As far as I've read, using an IDE converter can be a tricky job and there are some variables including chip manufacturer, etc. Is there anyone that have been used one of the above solutions without experiencing transfer problems / buffer underrun/ loss of quality? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of getting standardized performance out of your IDE drive, the best advice I can give you is to add an [IDE controller card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816124009&cm_re=ide_controller_card-_-16-124-009-_-Product) to your PC so that you can get a direct IDE to bus connection going over the PCI or PCI-E interface. I've had bad luck getting SATA > IDE adapters to work and would not recommend them.

The big problem here is that an IDE controller card costs about as much as, if not more than, [a new SATA DVD-RW drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA10V45V8081&cm_re=DVD-rW_drive-_-9SIA10V45V8081-_-Product), which would also yield increased performance. It might make more sense simply to bite the bullet and upgrade the drive.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it looks like IDE to PCI(e) it's a decent solution. U're right but the mentioned unit have a Yamaha chipset inside that support [AMQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_recording_modes#Audio_Master_Quality_Recording) that's why I am interested to make it work somehow not to upgrade, on the new setup environment  :) I'll have to [read more](http://club.myce.com/f138/ide-controllers-definitive-thread-90930/) about IDE controllers.